# Probleme schema Design mongodb nodejs mongoos

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-design

Im trying to create a knew schema mongodb like this :

```
  `const badgeSchema = new Schema({
   emt: { type: String, required: true },
   modele: { type: String, required: true },
   code: { type: String, required: false },
   classe: { type: String, required: false },
    });`
```

but i want to add another property model 'codage' , it is combination between code and class and '10000' :

```
 `codage: { type: String, codage+classe+'1000'},`
```

exemple codage = 00048 and classe = 01072 ===> codage = 000480107210000

```
   `const badgeSchema = new Schema({
    emt: { type: String, required: true },
    modele: { type: String, required: true },
   code: { type: String, required: false },
   classe: { type: String, required: false },
    codage: { type: String, ????????????? }
     });`
```

exemple codage = 00048 and classe = 01072 ===> codage = 000480107210000

Comment: Won't keeping `codage` in sync with `code` and `classe` become a nightmare?  Anytime a dependent value is updated, `codage` will also need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in mongoose using [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html). This is an example from the Mongoose documentation:

> ```js
> const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
>  email: String
> });
>
> // Create a virtual property `domain` that's computed from `email`.
> userSchema.virtual('domain').get(function() {
>  return this.email.slice(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1);
> });
>
> const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
>
> const doc = await User.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
> // `domain` is now a property on User documents.
> doc.domain; // 'gmail.com'
> ```

Substituting in the fields you have, it might look like this:

```js
badgeSchema.virtual('codage').get(function() {
  return this.code + this.classe + '10000';
});
```